# По нажатии на кнопку показать новое окно внутри того, на котором кнопка

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

Я новичок в Qt и не до конца понимаю следующей вещи:
У меня есть основное окно, в котором есть некая область и кнопка. По нажатии на кнопку нужно, чтобы в этой области появилось другое окно, но не совсем понимаю, как сделать, чтобы новое окно появлялось именно внутри основного. (не понимаю, какого типа должна быть сама область и что писать в слоте кнопки)

Пример:

[image: firstwin]

По нажатии на кнопку button в выделенной области должно появиться следующее окно:

[image: secwin]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете добавить через редактор необходимую область(например, widget с необходимыми элементами внутри), скрыть ее, используя  `ui->widget->setVisible(false);`, а в слоте кнопки включить обратно.
Если вам нужно именно окно внутри другого окна, стоит рассмотреть mdiArea - [QMdiArea Class](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmdiarea.html)

Answer (score 0):

Сначала создадим то самое второе окно:
window2* w;
Это окно в конструкторе должно иметь эту область
w = new window2(ui->область);
После этого нужно просто показать созданное окно внутри другого:
w.show();
Надеюсь, разберёшься, поменять названия переменных не так уж и сложно.